# reading from stdin, while consuming no more memory than needed

Tags: python, pipe, stdin, line-by-line

I am trying to create a line-by-line filter in python.  However, `stdin.readlines()` reads all lines in before starting to process, and python runs out of memory (`MemoryError`).

How can I have *just one line* in memory at a time?

The kind of code I have:

```
for line in sys.stdin.readlines():
    if( filter.apply( line ) ):
        print( line )
```

(note: I'm on 2.6)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
for line in sys.stdin:
    ...
```

Or call `.readline()` in a loop.

Answer (score 2):

```
import sys
while 1:
    line = sys.stdin.readline()
    if not line:
        break
    if (filter.apply(line)):
        print(line)
```